# Is there the flat Minkowski spacetime, or is it a mathematical idealization?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, approximations

The occurrence of events always requires the passage of time and displacement in space. For this, we need to have a minimum of spacetime curvature.
I think that the flat Minkowski spacetime doesn't exist in our universe.

Comment: "For this, we need to have a minimum of spacetime curvature." This seems unjustified. Why do you think time and space don't work in Minkowski spacetime?

Comment: If we talk about space-time then time moves regardless if it is curved or flat. If we talk about spatial curvature  then time doesn't move per definition regardless if it is curved or flat.

Comment: @Javier -  I think gravity is the stage or the base where things happen. Without this feature we have no events. Something physical to exist needs time and space. The scientific method needs empirical procedures to explain the facts. How to check something that does not exist?

Comment: You have no basis for "without feature we have no events". Physics in Minkowski space is perfectly sound, you can certainly have events.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mathematical idealization. For example, even distant galaxies cause a tiny amount of curvature at our location. Also, there is no shielding against gravity like there is against electromagnetism. But there is no conceptual problem with doing physics in flat Minkowski spacetime. Specifically, particles move, and fields evolve, just fine. There is no gravity in flat spacetime, but the three other forces work.

Comment: When I say "there is no gravity in flat spacetime" I mean there is no purely metric theory of gravity in flat spacetime. But there are non-metric theories for gravity-like forces, such as Nordstrom's scalar theory, which work fine in flat spacetime.